# Classic ASP updating data via AJAX

Tags: sql, ajax, asp-classic

Hey all i am trying to figure out how to go about updating my current code so that i do not have to refresh the page to do so.

However, i am not sure how i can do that considering how my asp code is layed out.

My example code is:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Dim Connection
Dim ConnString
Dim Recordset
Dim row1(11)
Dim row2(11)
Dim row3(11)
...
Dim row29(11)
Dim intX
Dim shift(19)

ConnString="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxxxx;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxxxx;DATABASE=rtd"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.RTDtable ORDER BY ID"

Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Connection.Open ConnString
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection

If Recordset.EOF Then
    Response.Write("No records returned.")
Else
    intX = 0

    Do While NOT Recordset.Eof   
        row1(intX) = Recordset("Production_Date")
        row2(intX) = Recordset("GroupID")
        row3(intX) = Recordset("Shift")
        row4(intX) = Recordset("Shift_Name")
        row5(intX) = Recordset("Full_Shift")
        row6(intX) = Recordset("Stn_ID")
        row7(intX) = Recordset("Stn_ID2")
        row8(intX) = Recordset("Point_Name")
        row9(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_1")
        row10(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_2")
        row11(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_3")
        row12(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_4")
        row13(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_5")
        row14(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_6")
        row15(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_7")
        row16(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_8")
        row17(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_9")
        row18(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_10")
        row19(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_11")
        row20(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_12")
        row21(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_13")
        row22(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_14")
        row23(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_15")
        row24(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_16")
        row25(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_17")
        row26(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_18")
        row27(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_19")
        row28(intX) = Recordset("Bucket_20")
        row29(intX) = Recordset("Total")

        intX = IntX + 1
        Recordset.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing
%>
```

And after calling that i do this to insert it into the table:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tableHeading">1680-1L</td>
    <td valign="bottom"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgDetails_ctl06_lblDowntime"></span></td>
    <td align="left" class="fontSizes">ACTUAL</td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row9(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row10(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row11(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row12(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row13(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row14(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row15(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row16(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row17(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row18(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row19(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row20(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row21(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row22(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row23(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row24(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row25(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row26(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row27(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row28(1) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row29(1) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td valign="bottom"></td>
    <td align="left" class="fontSizes">TARGET</td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row9(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row10(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row11(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row12(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row13(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row14(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row15(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row16(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row17(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row18(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row19(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row20(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row21(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row22(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row23(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row24(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row25(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row26(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row27(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row28(2) %></td>
    <td align="right"><% response.write row29(2) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
etc etc
```

So how would i do this update via AJAX since i have that in the html code?

Thanks for your time,

David

**GET example:**

```
$.get('resultPage.asp', function(data) { 
  // Extract just the HTML for the table 
  var ixTableStart = data.indexOf('<td', data.indexOf('id="Row9-1"')); 
  var ixTableEnd = data.indexOf('</td>', ixTableStart) + 8; 
  var resultTableHtml = data.substring(ixTableStart, ixTableEnd); 
  $('.Row9-1).html(resultTableHtml); 

etc etc...
}); 

 <tr>
    <td class="tableHeading">1680-1L</td>
    <td valign="bottom"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgDetails_ctl06_lblDowntime"></span></td>
    <td align="left" class="fontSizes">ACTUAL</td>
    <td align="right" id="row9-1">51</td>
    <td align="right" id="row10-1">10</td>
    <td align="right" id="row11-1">16</td>
    etc.....
 <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td valign="bottom"></td>
    <td align="left" class="fontSizes">TARGET</td>
    <td align="right" id="row9-2">5</td>
    <td align="right" id="row10-2">16</td>
    etc...
```

Comment: Are you looking for basic javascript solutions, or something including a framework, such as jQuery, will be acceptable?

Comment: Ok, next question. What are you updating? You are just updating the values displayed in the table? Or the user has some data they are updating back to the server? What should the AJAX be accomplishing?

Comment: @GuthMD: Its all static data being called from a stored procedure. So all i need it to do is recall the SP and display the new data amounts in the tables.

Comment: So, you are trying to update per single row? I'm afraid I'm confused as to the question. Can you give an example use case? e.g., user browses to your results page, user then... refreshes page? goes to a page of different results?

Comment: right now you would just have to refresh the page to get updated values. Instead of doing that i want it to do that behind the scenes and without the need to refresh the page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9333/discussion-between-guthmd-and-stealthrt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you are doing is refreshing the page, specifically the results displayed in a table, either through a button click, or through a `setInterval` javascript method.

Assuming you have your results `<table>` in a `<div>` or similar container elements with `id` attribute `resultPanel` and a number, then you can use the following:

```
$.get('resultPage.asp', function(data) {
  FillResultPanel("resultPanel1");
  FillResultPanel("resultPanel2");
  FillResultPanel("resultPanel3");
  FillResultPanel("resultPanel4");
});
function FillResultPanel(panelId) {
  // Extract just the HTML for the table
  var ixTableStart = data.indexOf('<table', data.indexOf('id="' + panelId + '"'));
  var ixTableEnd = data.indexOf('</table>', ixTableStart) + 8;
  var resultTableHtml = data.substring(ixTableStart, ixTableEnd);
  $('#' + panelId).html(resultTableHtml);
}
```

**Edit:** As you mentioned in chat that you had 4 tables to update, I updated my solution to provide an example specific to that scenario.

Comment: Hum... would that represent the rowX(X) numbers within the table?

Comment: All that does is to get the page again in an asynchronous GET request, then replace the existing table markup with the refreshed page. Do you need to change rows, or in any other way modify *which* results are displayed on the page?

Comment: So are you saying the code just injects the full table struction in HTML? So the resultPage.asp page would only have the code to get the SP and also the HTML for the tables? Then the jquery places all that html tables data that it "gets" into the main page where it finds the tags?

Comment: @StealthRT Right. It's essentially just the same as a Refresh from the browser, only it updates just the results table, and does so through AJAX, to prevent and reload. Am I understanding the question correctly?  Also, you will need to replace `resultPage.asp` with whatever is the name of your current asp page.

Comment: Well all that code i posted above is only on one page. Would it be possible to give each section of the table that has the data an ID and then in the jQuery just call out to that ID and insert that data it gets from the GET?

Comment: Check out the OP. I updated to what i was talking about in my previous comment. The GET example:. It finds the ID of the <TD> and finds the data for that id from the GET and inserts it over the current value, etc etc.